# ArraySum of a list

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to add all the values of all the numbers in a list.

So this is what I tried,

```
<cfloop query="get_total_merchant">
    <cfset tx_amt_total = #tx_amount# + (#tx_amount# * (#merchantFee#/100))>
    #ArraySum(tx_amt_total)#
</cfloop>
```

So basically what `tx_amt_total` will display is something like `1 2 3 4`. So I am trying to add 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 which should give me 10.

However, from what I tried, I am getting an error message: `Object of type class java.lang.Double cannot be used as an array`

So how do I fix my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<cfset tx_amt_total = 0 />

<cfloop query="get_total_merchant">
    <cfset tx_amt_total += (tx_amount + (tx_amount * (merchantFee/100))) />
</cfloop>
```

should be enough. You don not need arraySum()